# SQL Server: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am confused about why this doesn't work:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

COMMIT

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Accounts ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_client_not_null CHECK (site <> 'LWOP' and client is not null)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Accounts SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO

COMMIT
```

will throw this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 13
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_client_not_null". The conflict occurred in database "ss", table "dbo.Accounts".
>
> Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

but when I run the following:

```
select *
from Accounts
where site = 'LWOP' or client is null
```

I am getting only that row that can have client as null.

What am I missing here?

Once again: I want to make a constraint that will restrict null values on client column ONLY if site <> 'LWOP', so how to do it?

Thanks,
Dejan

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution already:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Accounts ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_client_not_null CHECK (site <> 'LWOP' and client is not null OR site = 'LWOP')
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Accounts SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

site <> 'LWOP' and client is not null **OR site = 'LWOP'** - that covers all situations for check to work.

Comment: @JacobH, this answer is from OP.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance This will not execute successfully unless null data will be cleared before adding the constraint. Here is the demo for illustration https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=648f5bc16a27954128e693139337bc3a

Comment: Agreed Suraj, that's correct, but the table was already prepared for the check constant. I don't think about that check to work on a existing set all situations have to be true

Comment: @dedo OK Got it, I was also wrong at the start and corrected myself after testing and suggested by what Shannon_Severance. Thank you.